# MySQL join and fields from the second table as columns in result

Tags: mysql, join

I was wondering if my approach is adequate, possible and how would I do it?

Consider you have a 2 MySQL tables:

**TABLE A**

```
ID   alias     
--   --
11   banner_a
26   banner_b
```

**TABLE B**

```
Column  Type
pid         int(10) 
lang    varchar(2)  
field   varchar(255)    
value   text
```

And example data for TABLE B:

```
id  lang    field               value

26  da      banner_type         single
26  da      priority            5
26  da      timing              5

26  de      banner_type         single
26  de      priority            1
26  de      timing              10
```

So, assuming I'd like to select all/some records from TABLE A, and their related fields with values from TABLE B, grouped by lang. Where field from table B is selected like a regular column in MySQL, and it's value would be field's value.

Expecting to see results like this:

result record 1:

```
id 26
alias banner_b
lang da
banner_type single
priority 5
timing 5
```

result record 2:

```
id 26
alias banner_b
lang de
banner_type single
priority 5
timing 5
```

I did something like that a few years ago, I think with COALESCE, but it's not what I want.

Where should I start if at all? :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  b.id, 
  b.lang,
  MAX(CASE WHEN b.field = 'banner_type' THEN b.value END) AS 'banner_type',
  MAX(CASE WHEN b.field = 'priority' THEN b.value END) AS 'priority',
  MAX(CASE WHEN b.field = 'timing' THEN b.value END) AS 'timing'
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY b.id, b.lang;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32bf7/7)

This will give you:

```
| ID | LANG | BANNER_TYPE | PRIORITY | TIMING |
-----------------------------------------------
| 26 |   da |      single |        5 |      5 |
| 26 |   de |      single |        1 |     10 |
```

**Note that:** In the query I used `MAX`. Because, each group `id  lang` in the table `TableB` has two values for each `BANNER_TYPE | PRIORITY | TIMING` so which value do you want for each group?